# MS Word: select text inside a table cell

Tags: ms-word, selection

I need to select a text (for example, two chars) inside a cell in a table in a Word document. The following code:

```
Sub testTable()
For Each itable In ActiveDocument.Tables
       itable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Select 
Next
End Sub
```

selects all the content of the second cell in the first row of the table. How have I to modify it to select only a subset of the cell content, for example from the 4th char to the 9th char?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Range object has a Characters property, so:

```
itable.Cell(1,2).Range.Characters(4).Select
Selection.MoveEnd wdCharacter, 5
```

Another way to go about it is to work with Range objects:

```
Dim rng as Word.Range
Set rng = itable.Cell(1,2).Range.Characters(4)
rng.End = itable.Cell(1,2).Range.Characters(9)
```

And there are variations on the theme...

Comment: The last line `rng.End = itable.Cell(1,2).Range.Characters(9)` didn't work for me but `rng.End = rng.End + 9` or `rng.End = aCell.Range.Characters(9).End` works.